# Recovering a lost Stack Overflow account with no email set up

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, faq-proposed

When I started using Stack Overflow, Google was not an OpenID provider yet, so I used this [OpenID Provider app](http://openid-provider.appspot.com/) instead, and I actually forgot that I was using it. But now when I try to log in I am getting this error:

> **The following required parameters were missing from the PositiveAssertionResponse message: dnoa.op_endpoint**

As I doubt that anyone is maintaining that application anymore and I don't think that it will get fixed by itself, does anyone know a way to move my old account to a new one and that way recover my reputation without having to send an email to the "contact us" link?

My old Stack Overflow account was this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85093?tab=stats#tab-top).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without ownership, proving ownership is the tricky thing; however, I'm satisfied that you are you and have updated your account accordingly. Try going to [account recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) now, and using the e-mail associated with your meta account.

If that doesn't work, you can create a *new* registered stackoverflow account; we can then merge the two.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. First thing did not work. In the email I received the opendid parameters that does not work. Then I created a new stackoverflow account using google an it automatically merged the accounts as behind the scenes opendid credentials were the same (or something like that, my knowledge about openid is quite limited as you can see :-) ). Well finally it seems there was no problem at all. Thanks again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/707751/maidul       This is my Old account . I have creates new account. http://stackoverflow.com/users/4604782/maidul-islam      and this one http://stackoverflow.com/users/4604752/user4604752 . I forgot my old email id too. So please merge my new new account with respective of one of old accounts. Let me know if any more details. @Marc Gravell

Comment: @Maid786 please use `http://stackoverflow.com/contact` and select "I need to merge user profiles"; if you can't use the automated approach, use "Other"